# Code to redirect after updating database

Tags: php, mysql

I have a register page(index.php). It takes two values "username" and "password" and the database updation with those values takes place on registrartion.php page. I want code to redirect the registration.php page to again index.php page after updating my database while displaying a message that you have been successfully registered. Help in this regard.
Thanks

registration.php

```
 <?php

 $host="l888888"; // Host name 
 $username="******"; // Mysql username 
 $password="t******"; // Mysql password 
 $db_name="f****"; // Database name 
 $tbl_name="m******"; // Table name 

 // Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['username']; 
mypassword=$_POST['password']; 


 // To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);

$query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(`username`,`password`) VALUES     ('$myusername','$mypassword')"); 


   if($query)
        header('Location: /home/faltutal/public_html/treasurehunt/index.php');
```

?>

if I use
header('Location:index.php')

error showing 
 Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/faltutal/public_html/treasurehunt/registration.php:2)

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: @Touki here comes a 1^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect using header() function by passing location:path:
-If you want to display any message you can pass it through index.php?msg=your_message or flag

```
<?php 
      $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(`username`,`password`) 
                    VALUES('$myusername','$mypassword')"); 
       if($query)
            header('Location: http://my_ip/index.php.php?msg=added successfully');
?>
```

OR : you can display message in register.php file and by clicking on link you can redirect to the index.php file as bellow

```
<?php 
      $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(`username`,`password`) 
                    VALUES('$myusername','$mypassword')"); 
       if($query)
            echo "Successfully Added <a href='http://my_ip/index.php'>Click Here to Continue</a>";
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try with redirect like

```
<?php 
      $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(`username`,`password`) 
                    VALUES('$myusername','$mypassword')"); 
       if($query)
            header('Location: http://my_ip/mainpage.php.php');
?>
```

For header function php refer this [**LINK**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: error shows upWarning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/faltutal/public_html/treasurehunt/registration.php:2) in /home/faltutal/public_html/treasurehunt/registration.php on line 32

Comment: Then check your php starting and ending tags....whether they are all closed nicely..??

Comment: But there is not any mismatching of tags. or may be I cant find one.

Comment: please check again. I have posted the code in my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if ($query) { // if it's true
 header('Location: http://yoursite.com/index.php');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [header()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) function you can redirect the page where ever you wants.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue.. Even though most of the answers given worked fine on desktop, i realised i was still getting the **headers already sen**t error on mobile. I found the solution on this page [How to auto redirect page](http://www.wp3layouts.com/wp/php-auto-redirect-page-form-submission-database/)

If anyone is having same desktop and mobile issue use the **ob_start()** and **ob_end_flush()** functions around the **insert** command.

```
<?php ob_start();
        $query=mysql_query("INSERT INTO members(`username`,`password`) 
                VALUES('$myusername','$mypassword')"); 
        if($query)
        header('Location: http://my_ip/index.php.php?msg=added successfully');

    ob_end_flush(); ?>
```